# Smart pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

every one!
I've got a problem. I want to merge two pandas DataFrame by same column, where the 1st DataFrame in his column contains values of column 2nt DataFrame. And i want to keep in result values of 1st DataFrame, where they exist, and where they isn't keep values from 2nt. Like this:

1st:

_    col_1    col_2

0    123    100

1    124    200

2    125    150

3    126    250

4    127    300

2nt:

_    col_1    col_2

0    123    10

1    125    20

2    127    30

And i want to get next one:

_   col_1    col_2

0    123    10

1    124    200

2    125    20

3    126    250

4    127    30

Answer (score 0):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True)
        .drop_duplicates('col_1')
        .sort_values('col_1'))
print (df)
   col_1  col_2
0    123     10
4    124    200
1    125     20
6    126    250
2    127     30
```